# Wake-on-LAN with USB3 ethernet adaptor?

Tags: macos, usb, sleep-wake, wake-on-lan

My 2019 MBPR has an USB-C ethernet adaptor. I've been running it with the display closed and having a difficult time getting Wake-On-Lan to work.

I'm hoping that macOS Ventura is smart enough to keep power to USB-C accessories (i.e. an ethernet adaptor) when asleep so that Wake-on-lan works.

Is there a way to determine if an accessory supports WOL and/or how I can verify the OS is set up properly to enable this feature?

Comment: Have a look at this adapter: [StarTech USB31000SW](https://www.amazon.com/USB-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Adapter/dp/B00BCVUIIU?th=1). It claims to support WoL.  I haven’t tested it, but you might want to give it a shot.

Comment: FWIW, I tried that adaptor and it has no effect.

Comment: I actually tried researching out-of-band (OOB) or lights-out-management (LOM) that can function over USB and there was nothing available (that I could find).  Even at the enterprise level, this is only done via console (UART or dedicated LOM interface).  Nothing USB.  I don’t think this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Pretty disappointing then that there appears to be no way to WOL a MacBook pro.